# Magento 2 - Admin product page layout issue

Tags: magento2, product, cache, admin-panel, page-layouts

I am facing an issue while trying to go on the product page from a catalog in the admin. The product page grid layout not loading properly. Every time when I clear cache, page load correctly. What is the issue? Need help

1. requirejs error in the console

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of console log

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

chmod -R 777 pub/ var/ generated/ app/
```

Comment: I will try this and and let you know the result .

Comment: Never set 777 permission to `app/` folder. And I would suggest not to give 777 permission to all folders and files in `www` directory. Reason: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777/20110#20110](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777/20110#20110)